# Unable to access table inside div (basketballreference)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently writing a Python script and part of it gets winshares from the first 4 seasons of every player's career in the NBA draft between 2005 and 2015. I've been messing around with this for almost 2 hours (getting increasingly frustrated), but I've been unable to get the Win Shares for the individual players. I'm trying to use the "Advanced" table at the following link as a test case: https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/bogutan01.html#advanced::none

When getting the player's names from the draft pages I had no problems, but I've tried so many iterations of the following code and have had no success in accessing the td element the stat is in.

```
playerSoup = BeautifulSoup(playerHtml)
        playertr = playerSoup.find_all("table", id = "advanced").find("tbody").findAll("tr")
        playerws = playertr.findAll("td")[21].getText()
```

Comment: this page use JavaScript to add data. `requests` and  `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You can use `Selenium` to control web browser which will load page and run javascript and then you can get HTML with Selenium. OR use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see all requests from browser to server and find url used by JavaScript to get data. Use this url with `requests` to get data. JavaScript mostly get data in JSON format which you can easily convert to python's dictionary and get data without BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I checked HTML and this page has all data in HTML as comments `<!-- ... ->` so you could get it without JavaScript but you have to find correct comment (using Beautifulsoup), remove `<!-- ... ->` and use it in Beautifulsoup as normal HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page use `JavaScript` to add tables but it doesn't read data from server. All tables are in HTML but as comments `<!-- ... ->`

Using `BeautifulSoup` you can find all comments and then check which one has text `"Advanced"`. And then you can use this comment as normal HTML in `BeautifulSoup`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/bogutan01.html#advanced::none'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

all_comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

for item in all_comments:
    if "Advanced" in item:
        adv = BeautifulSoup(item)

        playertr = adv.find("table", id="advanced")

        if not playertr:
            #print('skip')
            continue # skip comment without table - go back to `for`

        playertr = playertr.find("tbody").findAll("tr")
        playerws = adv.find_all("td")[21].getText()

        print('playertr:', playertr)
        print('playerws:', playerws)

        for row in playertr:
            if row:
                print(row.find_all('th')[0].text)
                all_td = row.find_all('td')
                print([x.text for x in all_td])
                print('--')
```

Comment: Within the if statement for `if "Advanced' in item:` I am still getting a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'` attribute error.

Comment: These are the lines it cites:

`playertr = adv.find("table", id="advanced").find("tbody").findAll("tr")
                playerws = adv.find_all("td")[21].getText()
`

Comment: you have to split `find().find()` into two lines and check result after first `find`

Comment: see new code in answer. It finds two tables with word "Advanced". You may try to find better method to recognize correct table. Probably first table is correct so you could use `break` to exit `for` loop and skip second table.

Comment: I made some edits in my own code that are working but when I get to Chris Paul (https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/p/paulch01.html#advanced::none) I get an index out of range error on the line: `playerws = [adv.findAll("td")[i].getText() for i in` indicies]. My code is as follows:

`print(len(adv.findAll("td")))
                indicies = [21,49,77,105]
                playerws = [adv.findAll("td")[i].getText() for i in indicies] `

Comment: what do you get with `print(len(adv.findAll("td")))` ? Is this smaller then 105 in your `indicies` ? Or maybe you count from 1 but Python count from 0 zero.

Comment: It's 0 for this specific player. That's why I'm confused. I investigated it and it appears the formatting is identical.

Comment: it seems it has more comments with `"Advanced"` and first is not table. I put `continue` in answer to skip comment which don't have table.

Comment: Works like a charm.